# source code can't find the include header files?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, fortran, header-files

I have huge source codes, most of it written in Fortran90 language however some parts are in C language. This code in order to be compiled correctly need MPI and HDF5 to be installed. I have installed them now when I try to compile the model (compilation is not with `./compile` command there is `./install.sh` instead and it take care of everything including compilation). I have the a long error and all related to the path of the header files. Here is the error:

```
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h 
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h 
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h  
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: mpif.h   
Can't find file: mpif.h
Can't find file: stdio.h
Can't find file: math.h
Can't find file: stdlib.h
Can't find file: malloc/malloc.h
Can't find file: malloc.h
Can't find file: stdlib.h
Can't find file: errno.h
Can't find file: string.h
Can't find file: ctype.h
Can't find file: dirent.h
Can't find file: string.h
```

and there are some other errors after that which I believe they are associated to the above errors. I have tried to set the PATH in ./bashrc and when I search for example locate mpif.h it returns:

```
[hamid@localhost bin]$ locate mpif.h
   /home/hamid/Downloads/ED-2.1/ED/build/bin/mpif.h
   /home/hamid/Downloads/ED-2.1/ED/src/mpi/mpif.h
   /home/hamid/Downloads/mpich-3.1.3/src/binding/fortran/mpif_h/mpif.h
   /home/hamid/Downloads/mpich-3.1.3/src/binding/fortran/mpif_h/mpif.h.in
   /home/hamid/Downloads/mpich-3.1.3/src/include/mpif.h
   /home/hamid/mpich2-optimised/include/mpif.h
```

and also I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MPI_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But still it seems it's not working. My guess is it is not just related to MPI or HDF path setting because some of them are GCC (C compiler) header files. 
Any idea on what could be the problem?

Comment: You need to use the `-I` option to `gcc` to tell it where to find header files.

Comment: Headers are not located using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Use the `-I` option to tell it which directory(ies) contain your headers.

Comment: Thanks guys I dont know where to put -I since as i mentioned the compilation of the model is not like simple compiling with ./compile, make and make install. instead it has ,;/install bash script. in case of interest [here](https://github.com/EDmodel/ED2/wiki/Quick-start) is more description, i am following quick installation section.

Comment: I assume that you have a makefile to do all this work.  In the line like: gcc $(CFLAGS) -c currentfile.c -o currentfile.o -Ipathtoheaders

Comment: Is there a file called configure or config.in or something like that?  You may have to run something like `make configure` to configure the makefile first.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, you can use `-I` to specify a directory, the compiler will then find `.h` files there. E.g.:

```
gfortran -o name.o -c -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include name.f90
```

If you are using `ifort`, an alternative is to append the directory to `FPATH`, perhaps:

```
FPATH=$FPATH:usr/lib/openmpi/include
```

This does not work with gfortran though. I don't know about other compilers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your installation script is trying to use a regular compiler to compile an MPI code, that's why all those headers are not being found. Try adding your mpich binary directory to your path.